# How to fix a missing vcruntime140 clr 400 dll error

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-7, system-administration

I'm trying to run a windows form application on a windows 7 machine. The application is written in C# under .NET framework. Whenever I try to run the application, it says that VCRUNTIME140_CLR400.dll is missing.

I've tried to google the solution, but I can't find anything about this specific dll.
The only results I get are from VCRUNTIME140.dll. Or are they one and the same?

Comment: [The latest supported Visual C++ downloads](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads)

Comment: That app might have used C++/CLR, which requires VC++ runtime to be installed, https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=48145 "140" maps to 2015 release. The xx140_CLRxx.dll is different from xx140.dll

Comment: Lex Li, why don't you put it as an answer?