# install wxWidget as static library by Vcpkg

Tags: visual-studio, compilation, shared-libraries, wxwidgets

I'm using Visual studio 2019

I followed this link to install wxWidget using  `vcpkg install wxwidgets`
https://www.wxwidgets.org/blog/2019/01/wxwidgets-and-vcpkg/

and read this link

https://computingonplains.wordpress.com/using-visual-studio-2017-to-build-wxwidgets/

and this

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/vcpkg-updates-static-linking-is-now-available/

the problem after installing wxWidget using **vcpkg** the result build is Dynamic library and I want to compile my project as static library to run exe file  on other users pc .
 I want to change from Dynamic lib compilation to static due to :
users on another PCs get VCRUNTIME error so they have to install  VC++ runtime library as I read in

[How to fix a missing vcruntime140 clr 400 dll error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59105264/how-to-fix-a-missing-vcruntime140-clr-400-dll-error)

Summary of the problem  : 
vcpkg installation  wxwidgets  result is dynamic lib configuration and I need to install static one .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@MohmmedAlaa,

You are better off compiling the library yourself.

There is a big difference between compiling the project with wxWidgets being dynamic vs static and VC++ RT dynamic vs static.

Also, keep in mind that some VC++ RT is not licensed to be distributable.

So all in all - get the wxWidgets sources, install MSVC, build static libraries (possibly with the compiler switch to use "static RT) and compile your software.

Comment: +1 On this. It'll be way easier to compile wxWidgets to a static lib than doing it through vcpkg. Remember to set the appropriate flags for static linking

Comment: Done with adding a custom template for project , I don't have to modify each new project every time

Comment: @igor `There is a big difference between compiling the project ... being dynamic vs static and VC++ RT dynamic vs static.`  What EXACTLY does this mean?  What does the mystery abbreviation _RT_ stand for?  In fact, wouldn't all readers benefit if all the mystery abbreviations you are using were defined?

Comment: @zipzit, how familiar are you with the compiling/lining/executing process? All abbreviation I'm using are very familiar to software development world. And if you are just starting you should get acquaint with the terminology  Otherwise you will not go too far. And you certainly shouldn't be looking at the library such as wxWidgets when youo just starting you journey. Get familiar with C++ and then come back and reread my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of just doing `vcpkg install wxwidgets`
use `vcpkg install wxwidgets:x64-windows-static`

This will install wxwidgets and all it dependencies with static runtime and library linkage.

You can also define your custom triplet if you want to customize your build setup (see https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/blob/master/docs/users/triplets.md)